# Importing theano with GPU device on Windows conda

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I'm having some troubles working with a workstation with Conda for Windows. I'm not too familiar with the OS and this is the first time I try GPU support for theano there, to no avail.

The thing is, when I use an Anaconda bash, I can put this:

`set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU"
set THEANO_FLAGS=device=cuda
python
import theano`

This works fine, with GPU support. However, I need the script to switch between devices (GPUs and CPU) during the execution. I read somewhere it can be done by setting the environment variables directly on the code, but I tried this to no avail:

`import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "device=cuda"
import theano`

The MKL_THREADING_LAYER environment variable is already put in the system, so I guess the error isn't there. Anyways, the code can't run:

`RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>`

Any ideas? Thanks.